# Is tail recursion merely a special case of CPS?

Tags: javascript, tail-recursion, continuations

I've implemented `map` in tail recursive and continuation passing style. Both versions are quite similar:

```
var inc = x => ++x;
var xs = [1,2,3,4,5];

var mapR = f => xs => {
    var rec = acc => {
        acc[acc.length] = f(xs[acc.length]);
        return acc.length < xs.length ? rec(acc) : acc;
    }

    return rec([]);
}

mapR(inc)(xs); // [2,3,4,5,6]

var mapC = f => xs => cc => {
    var rec = acc => cc => {
        acc[acc.length] = f(xs[acc.length]);
        return acc.length < xs.length ? cc(acc)(rec) : acc;
    }

    return cc(rec([])(rec));
}

mapC(inc)(xs)(console.log.bind(console)); // [2,3,4,5,6]
```

Instead of `cc(acc)(rec)` I obviously could have also wrote `rec(acc)`. Is my conclusion correct, that tail recursion is merely a special case of CPS and that `mapC` written with `var rec = acc => {...}` is a proper CPS function?

Comment: Actually, for true CPS, you shouldn't ever `return`. Also assume that `f` takes a continuation.

Comment: @Bergi But `() => { a(); }` becomes `() => { a(); return undefined; }` hence `a` wouldn't be in tail position anymore, or what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that CPS is tail calls on steriods, without ever really returning anything - you don't have a call stack, you just jump around to the next continuation. Of course this would need a special interpreter, and it's actually a horrible style of programming, but pocs have been built :-). Only if you call into cps from a non-cps code, `return`s make a bit or sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write that thing in pure CPS as the following:

```
const inc = x => cont => cont(x+1);

const map = f => xss => cont => {
    if (!xss.length) cont([]);
    else f(xss[0])(x => map(f)(xss.slice(1))(xs => cont([x].concat(xs))));
};

// or with an accumulator:
const mapA = f => xs => cont => {
    const rec = acc => {
        if (acc.length >= xs.length) cont(acc);
        else f(xs[acc.length])(x => {
            acc.push(x);
            rec(acc);
        });
    }
    rec([]);
};
```

> Is tail recursion merely a special case of CPS?

I wouldn't say so. CPS isn't much related to recursion at all.
However, CPS usually consists only of tail calls, which makes a stack superfluous - and the functions so powerful.

Comment: Yeah, definitely just typos :-) Thanks

Comment: `map` uses the call stack to temporarily store `x` (the respective result of `inc`) for each iteration. Doesn't this contradict the TCO principle? Sorry, but it's confusing when a function call is in tail position and when not...

Comment: I would say the closure stores it - the life time of `x` is bound to the life of the continuation, not of the call. `f` is in a tail call position here (and so is basically every other), the stack frame could be immediately reclaimed. Yes, it's scary…

Answer (score 2):

To be able to answer the question, the terms need to be clarified first:

1. **Recursion**: The calling of a function from within that same function
2. **Tail Call**: The last thing a function does before it returns is call another function
3. **Tail Recursion**: #1 and #2 combined
4. **Direct Style**: Sequential programming style characterized by functions, which return to their caller
5. **Continuation Passing Style (CPS)**: Programming style characterized by functions with an additional continuation argument, which call their continuation instead of returning to their caller (continuations are simply functions in Javascript)

How correlate these terms?

- Direct Style and Continuation Passing Style are opposing concepts of control flow
- Tail recursive calls are a specialization of tail calls
- Recursion and tail recursion are techniques of Direct Style
- Each (tail) recursive algorithm can be converted into its CPS form, because CPS has more expressive power than recursion

**Comparing tail recursion and CPS does not make sense**, because both techniques represent different paradigms of how control flow should be handled - even if they have quite similarities:

- Both can of course describe recursive control flows
- Both do without the call stack
- But: Tail recursion has a static, CPS a dynamic control flow (resolving which function is called next)

A final remark: CPS functions which describe a recursive algorithm store their data in recursively defined environments of anonymous functions (closures). That means, CPS doesn't use memory more efficient than recursion.